# Comment permission settings

Tags: users, comments

Please kindly help if you know a solution for this or a ready module you may be aware of:

1:I need to set a node a way that each user can only see their own comment and replies to that.
2:Also I need for some nodes, a user can see other users comments, only when he/she has a comment on that node already.
3: A group can see only each other comments on a node.

I hope this can be done by a setting when we are creating a node.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK there are no modules that provide the functionality of 1), 2) & 3) out of the box.

There is an awesome module [Comment Permissions](https://www.drupal.org/project/comment_perm) that can help you achieve better customization of comment permissions than Drupal core provides. You can take it as an example and expand the functionality that it already has to suit your needs.

> The Comment Permissions module enables control of commenting by user
>   role and by node type. Additional user permissions for selected node
>   types are added to the user access system so you can configure
>   commenting with more control than Drupal core provides.

Permissions provided by module (accessible via Permissions page & can be configured for each content type):

- administer comment settings on any page content
- administer comment settings on own page content
- comment on any page content
- comment without approval on any page content
- comment without approval on own page content
- edit own comments on page content

Hope this helps.